# Find changed rows (composite key with nulls)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Im trying to build a query that will fetch all changed rows from a source table, comparing it to a target table.

The primary key (its not really defined as a primary key, just what we know identifies an unique row) is a composite that consists of lots of foreign keys. Aproximatly about 15, most of which can have NULL values. For simplicity lets say the primary key consists of these three key columns and have 2 value fields that needs to be compared:

```
CREATE TABLE SourceTable 
(
    Key1 int NOT NULL,
    Key2 nvarchar(10),
    Key3 int,
    Value1 nvarchar(255),
    Value2 int
)
```

If Key1 = 1, Key2 = NULL and Key3 = 4. Then I would like to compare it to the row in target that has exactly the same values in the key fields. Including NULL in key 2.

The value fields can also have NULL values.

So whats the best approach to use when designing queries like this where NULL values should be considered as real values and compared?
ISNULL? COALESCE? Intersect?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Columns that participate in a PK are not allowed to be `NULL`.

Comment: Its not defined as a PK, so it can be NULL.

Comment: Are you comparing keys only or keys and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI SQL has the `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` construct that has not been implemented in SQL Server yet ([Connect request](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate)).

It is possible to [simulate this functionality](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) in SQL Server using `EXCEPT`/`INTERSECT` however. Both of these treat `NULL` as equal in comparisons. You are wanting to find rows where the key columns are the same but the value columns are different. So this should do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM   SourceTable S
       JOIN DestinationTable D
         ON S.Key1 = D.Key1
            /*Join the key columns on equality*/
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT S.Key2,
                                   S.Key3
                            EXCEPT
                            SELECT D.Key2,
                                   D.Key3)  
             /*and the value columns on unequality*/
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT S.Value1,
                                   S.Value2
                            INTERSECT
                            SELECT D.Value1,
                                   D.Value2)
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining this a tad more in plain language for less SQL adept folk. And me.

Comment: Thanks man. Except works perfectly. But one question. Why the join? Why not just select * from sourcetable except select * from destinationtable?

Comment: @gbn - Fixed. So it might make more sense now! `@user829237`. See edit and explanation. I don't think the version you were using did in fact work perfectly!

Comment: Thanks again. But if i also need all rows that does not exist in destination. Then i could just use SELECT * FROM SOURCETABLE EXCEPT SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONTABLE right?

Comment: @user829237 - Yes that will give you a set of rows in source but not in dest. But you won't be able to see what the changes are from that or use it in an update. i.e. you have no mapping between the row versions.

Comment: Brilliant. I learned something useful today :) Thanks Martin!

Comment: BTW. I just tested two different versions if this. One with EXCEPT / INTERSECT and one with ISNULL. Apparantly the ISNULL version i significantly faster. On a 500.000 recordset the ISNULL version runs in about 1-10 secs while the EXCEPT version uses about 30 secs.

Comment: Is this going to be efficient? If you have a data warehouse table of a million rows, and only 100 rows got updated, is this going to run smoothly?

Comment: @HeapofPintoBeans - it does an equality join on `Key1 ` so yes it can work efficiently and use hash, merge or nested loops joins. As always "it depends" though. For some specific case there might be a better approach. If you have a question about optimising some specific case you should ask it as a new question,

Answer (score 1):

Nulls don't play nice with foreign keys: changing a null to a value will not (in SQL Server) cause it to cascade when updated.

Best to avoid the null value (and for many other reasons too!) Instead get the DBA to nominate some other 'magic' value of the same data type but outside of the domain type. Examples: DATE: far distant or far future date value. INTEGER: zero or negative value. VARCHAR: value in double-curly braces to denote meta data value e.g. `'{{NONE}}'`, `'{{UNKNOWN}}'`, `'{{NA}}'`, etc then a `CHECK` constraint to ensure values cannot start/end with double curly braces.

Alternatively, model missing information by absence of a tuple in a relvar (closed world assumption) ;)