# Data warehouse: Figuring out what rows changed of a sql server table to facilitate data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row, data-warehouse

BUSINESS SCENARIO, SEEKING A WAY TO PROGRAM THIS:

Every night, I have to update table ABC in the data warehouse database from the production database. The table is millions of rows, so I want to do this efficiently.

The table doesn't have any sort of timestamp marker (LastUpdated Date\Time).

The database was created by our vendor whose software we run, and they are giving us visibility into our data.  We may not have much leverage in terms of asking for new columns to house information such as LastUpdate DateTime stamp.

Is there a way, absent such information, to be able to identify those rows that have changed or added.

For example, is there such a thing as query-able physical row number associated with the table record, that might help us work towards a solution?  If that could be queried, and perhaps go sequentially, then maybe there is a way to get the inserted rows.

Updated rows, I am not so sure.

Just entertaining ideas at this point in time to see if there is an efficient solution for this scenario.

Ideally, the solution will be geared towards a stored procedure we can have run every night be a job.

Thank you.

I saw this comment but I am not so sure that the solution is efficient:
[Find changed rows (composite key with nulls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877845/find-changed-rows-composite-key-with-nulls)

Comment: Your 1st option would be to try to implement CDC (change data capture), which will use features of the SQL Server engine to track such data. Please let us know if CDC is vailable option. [CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Piotr:  Not familiar, but if you know:  Is change data transaction information always there, and you have to tap into it, or it has to be enabled?  If its always there, I think the vendor can give us access to the data tables.  The source data is not managed by us.  Thanks

Comment: You need to enable it on source database, please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Please check the MERGE operator,You can create a SQL Server Job which can execute the MERGE Script to check and update the changes if any.